# When to create a new function in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, coding-style

The main question is when should I create a new function in powershell to make the code more maintainable.
Given the following :

```
    if ($Subtype -eq "Master" -and @($ColumnList | ? {$_.id -in $PK -and $_.name -like '*_SK'}).count -eq 1) {
        #TableColumnListPK for Master Data
        $global:TableColumnListPK = ($ColumnList | ? {$PK -match $_.id -and $_.name -like '*_SK'} | foreach {
            Create-AttributeWithDatatype        
        })
        
        #Column PK with only name-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        $global:PKName = @(($ColumnList | ? {$_.id -in $PK -and $_.name -like '*_SK'}).name)
                     
        #ColumnList non PK columns---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             
        $global:TableColumnListNonPK = $([string]::Join(",`r`n",($ColumnList | ? {($ColumnList | ? {$PK -match $_.id -and $_.name -like '*_SK'}).id -notmatch $_.id} | foreach {
            Create-AttributeWithDatatype            
         })))
        # Add comma after last column if it doesn't have one.
        if ($TableColumnListPK -notlike "*,") {
            $global:TableColumnListPK += ","
        }
    }
```

This is hard to read and is not very clear what is does so I split it up in functions of one line of code

```
    if (Is_Master_And_SK_As_PK) {
        $TableColumnListPK = Master_And_SK_As_PK_TableColumnListPK($PK,$ColumnList)
        $PKName = Master_And_SK_As_PK_PKName($PK,$ColumnList)
        $TableColumnListNonPK = Master_And_SK_As_PK_TableColumnListNonPK($PK,$ColumnList)
    }
```

where the function is only one line of code

```
function Master_And_SK_As_PK_PKName($PK,$ColumnList){
    #Column PK with only name-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $PKName = @(($ColumnList | ? {$_.id -in $PK -and $_.name -like '*_SK'}).name)
    return $PKName
}
```

Is the encapsulation here overkill ?
I dont find many resources on best practices in powershell. Most of the powershell code is written in one line where other languages would use multiple lines so it is not clear if I should create separate functions for this?
What is best approach to take here in powershell regarding Inderection ?

Comment: I think the word you're looking for is _indirection_ - this has nothing to do with encapsulation. Whether it's overkill or not is something you'll have to judge for yourself :-)

Comment: You should *always* allow your code to be more maintainable. It's just general good practice. This is opinion-based so I will offer mine. I personally prefer that creating multiple functions is better if you'll: a.) Re-using them a lot, or b.) There's a lot of code/ or any code that kind of *drifts* from the purpose of the script.  Like calling another function to find out info about the user you will use in your current script. Ultimately, it's preferance and should go off, of what you like better.

Comment: There's whole separate CodeReview site that *might* be a better place for this question - see https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, but for my £0.02 you can sometimes improve readability by assigning to temporary variables instead of creating functions if it's a one-off calculation - e.g. ```$isMasterAndSkAsPk = ...; if($isMasterAndSkAsPk) { ... }```

Comment: https://youtu.be/Lni4KjGMgu4. I recommend taking a look at this video for good script design practices, not from a syntax point of view.

Comment: Thanks all for the information. @AbrahamZinala I will check the video it might help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is [this] overkill

I wouldn't say so, although the question is somewhat subjective.

**If you're the primary maintainer, and it makes the code easier to read and maintain *for you*, then it's perfect** :-)

A few things you might want to change though:

#### Naming

PowerShell commands (including functions) should use the `Verb-Noun` format, ie.:

```
function Get-PKName($PrimaryKey,$ColumnList){
    $PKName = @(($ColumnList | ? {$_.id -in $PK -and $_.name -like '*_SK'}).name)
    return $PKName
}
```

#### Calling

PowerShell's command invocation syntax uses whitespace to separate parameter arguments, not a comma-separated list:

```
$PKName = Master_And_SK_As_PK_PKName($PK,$ColumnList)
# should be
$PKName = Master_And_SK_As_PK_PKName $PK $ColumnList
# or with a better name
$PKName = Get-PKName $PK $ColumnList
```

Comment: And it's good to know, that Microsoft encourages to use guidelines: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/strongly-encouraged-development-guidelines?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: I will be the primary maintainer but I'm new to powershell. I do have experience in other languages and there i like to split in lot of functions so i might do it here as well. Thanks !